# Seeing a Maven compiler error while running a selenium script using maven on Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, selenium, testing, jenkins

I am learning automation using selenium with maven. I wanted to learn the art of running the selenium code from jenkins( CI). I am doing most things right while setting up build item inside Jenkins, when I try to build the code from inside jenkins I get a maven compiler error, maven clean error. When I run the same code from the command line, the build succeeds and I am able to open the browser. Same  goes for running the code from inside the eclipse editor. The issue seems to be only when I run the script from inside jenkins.

I am attaching the error message here for everyones reference.

```html
Started by user vinyas Jain
Building in workspace /Users/vinyasjain/eclipse-workspace/testProject2
Parsing POMs
Established TCP socket on 60998
[testProject2] $ /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk/contents/Home/bin/java -cp /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven35-agent-1.12.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.0/libexec/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.0/libexec/conf/logging jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven35Main /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.0/libexec /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/war/WEB-INF/lib/remoting-3.27.jar /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven35-interceptor-1.12.jar /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-interceptor-commons-1.12.jar 60998
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
Executing Maven:  -B -f /Users/vinyasjain/eclipse-workspace/testProject2/pom.xml test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ---------------------< testProject2:testProject2 >----------------------
[INFO] Building testProject2 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ testProject2 ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.0:compile (default-compile) @ testProject2 ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.819 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-03-11T17:17:31+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.0:compile (default-compile) on project testProject2: Error while storing the mojo status: /Users/vinyasjain/eclipse-workspace/testProject2/target/maven-status/maven-compiler-plugin/compile/default-compile/inputFiles.lst (Permission denied) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[JENKINS] Archiving /Users/vinyasjain/eclipse-workspace/testProject2/pom.xml to testProject2/testProject2/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/testProject2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
channel stopped
Finished: FAILURE
```

Note:

- Issue seems to be related to deleting of files while compilation( target folder)
- I am working on a MAC operating system.

Help on this is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Root cause of your problem is wrong permissions for Jenkins:

> [ERROR] .... plugin/compile/default-compile/inputFiles.lst (Permission
>   denied) -> [Help 1]

When you start job via **Jenkins** you started your tests as *jenkins user* and this user haven't permissions to create/delete folders in your file system, when you start tests in command prompt you start tests as your *current user* and this user have more permissions

Please change permissions for **jenkins user** and try again or start Jenkins using **root user**

Comment: What are the permissions i'll need to change for the jenkins user and how do it do it ?

Comment: anyone has an answer for the above question on how to change permissions for jenkins user?

Comment: take a look on this answer to change permissions for jenkins user https://superuser.com/questions/114422/how-to-grant-admin-permissions-to-user-account-in-snow-leopard

Comment: I went through the above article and still don't see the solution for the problem.